# Deserialize source in native elasticsearch script plugin

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a native sort script & want to deserialize the source doc inside it (to access multi level nested objects). I can get the SourceLookup object using

```
SourceLookup source = source();
```

which gives me the bytes

```
byte[] bytes = source.internalSourceRef().toBytes()
```

What is the serialization format of these bytes and how can I deserialize it? Also what are the performance considerations of doing this operation? 
Does it require a disk access for each document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a look at the source code of [`SourceLookup`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e95af69fb71d67c3fb2a2806da24214dc4805140/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/lookup/SourceLookup.java) tells you a bit more about what you can find in there. That byte array is basically a serialized `Map` (possibly compressed) symbolizing the document source.

The way to use it is to call `source()` again on the `source` reference you get in order to retrieve the underlying `Map`:

```
SourceLookup source = source();
// number of keys in the map
int size = source.size();
// retrieve the content of the source
Map<String, Object> map = source.source();
// use the source map
```

Comment: Well this is the exact code I wrote after some debugging. Calling size() just to get loadSourceIfNeeded executed is a bit weird here. Also, it looks like the byte array is serialized json (possibly compressed), as the XContentType I get is JSON, but I couldn't find a reference for this, so hoping to get some clarity on the actual format. Another curious thing is that source.internalSourceRef() is always null.

Comment: The content type is indeed JSON, which gets reified as a Java `Map`. Since there are a few ways to create a `SourceLookup` instance, if `internalSourceRef` is null it's because the `SourceLookup.setSource()` method wasn't called in the first place, but the instance has been created by some other means. Hence why making sure that `loadSourceIfNeeded()` is called is the only surefire way to get a `Map` out of your source.